# Ionic 4 app asking blueooth permission on iOs 13

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I have an Ionic 4 app that runs without problems on iOs 12.2, but when I run it on iOs 13 it asks for bluetooth permissions right when the app starts.
The problem, aside giving permission to something that I didnt use, is that the app freezes depending on the anwser.
Here is the cordova section of my package.json:

```
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
  "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
  "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
    "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
  "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
  "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
  "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
  "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "28.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
    "APP_ID": "REDACTED",
    "CHANNEL_NAME": "REDACTED",
    "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com",
    "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
    "MAX_STORE": "2",
    "MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION": "30"
  },
  "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
  "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
  "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
  "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
  "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
    "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "REDACTED",
    "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.+",
    "LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires access to your location for navigation purposes"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": {
    "FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION": "17.0.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
    "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_TAGMANAGER_VERSION": "17.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION": "17.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "19.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "18.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "18.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "18.0.0",
    "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "2.10.1",
    "ANDROID_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "2.1.0",
    "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": false,
    "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": false,
    "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": false,
    "IOS_STRIP_DEBUG": true
  },
  "cordova-plugin-intercom": {},
  "call-number": {}
}
```

What could I do to prevent my app from ask for bluetooth permission?

Comment: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/365

Comment: Nice! I will look into it and will keep you updated.

Comment: Hey @DaveAlden, you are correct! Indeed, the problem is the diagnostic plugin. I removed it from my project and it worked. If you care to elaborate an answer I will upvote it and choose correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you use https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin this plugin?
if you don't need bluetooth feature, Please specify in Config.xml
<preference name=“cordova.plugins.diagnostic.modules” value=“LOCATION WIFI CAMERA NOTIFICATIONS MICROPHONE CONTACTS CALENDAR REMINDERS MOTION NFC EXTERNAL_STORAGE”>
and re-install the plugin and updated to app store
for IOS 13 we need to specify the usage of bluetooth.